# Why does HttpURLConnection not send the HTTP request

Tags: java, http, httpurlconnection

I would like to open an URL and submit the following parameters to it, but it only seems to work if I add the BufferedReader to my code. Why is that?

Send.php is a script what will add an username with a time to my database.

This following code does not work (it does not submit any data to my database):

```
        final String base = "http://awebsite.com//send.php?";
        final String params = String.format("username=%s&time=%s", username, time);
        final URL url = new URL(base + params);

        final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Agent");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.connect();
```

But this code does work:

```
        final String base = "http://awebsite.com//send.php?";
        final String params = String.format("username=%s&time=%s", username, time);
        final URL url = new URL(base + params);

        final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Agent");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.connect();

        final BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        connection.disconnect();
```

Comment: Consider using some third-part library if you need to work with HTTP. `Apache HttpClient` is pretty good. It's not very comfort to work with network with build-in Java facilities

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know. When you called the `connect()` function, it will only create the connection.

You need to at least call the `getInputStream()` or `getResponseCode()` for the connection to be committed so that the server that the url is pointing to able to process the request.

Comment: Looking at the JDK source code confirms.  The connection doesn't send the request until you call `getInputStream()`